# Compilation error using ffmpeg library

Tags: gcc, architecture, compilation, ffmpeg

I have downloaded and installed the ffmpeg library. I want to use it for reading the separate frames of different videos and manipulate them. For that I tried to follow some tutorial from here: http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/tutorial01.html
But I can't compile my cpp file since I get the following compilation:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "av_register_all()", referenced from:
      _main in cc9zyUBe.o
      _main in ccRz35d4.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

When I was installing ffmpeg library, I used arch=x86_64 option in ./configure step.
I use OS X Mountain Lion 10.8.2 and gcc 4.2 compiler.
Does somebody have any clue what can be the reason of this error?
Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:
I've already tried many different install options, with static libraries, shared libraries, with/without --arch=x86_64 option. Also installed it with homebrew, result remains the same. Library isn't recognized. But ffmpeg binary works pretty well, when I use it as a command-line tool.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally I have managed to compile my program which uses ffmpeg library.

For some reason I still couldn't compile it using gcc compiler, but I could do it with g++ compiler.

When the static libraries are installed, all the dependencies must be specified explicitly, and the order of linking of these libraries is also important. So here is the compilation code which finally compiled my program:

```
g++ readVideo.cc -o readVideo $(pkg-config --libs --cflags libavformat)
```

`pkg-config` here is a utility which prints all the flags and libraries that are needed to properly link the specified `libavformat` library.

Also it's worth of mentioning, that the source file was renamed from readVideo.C to readVideo.cc, and that `#include` statements have been encompassed using `extern "C"` as follows:

```
extern "C" {
  #include <libavformat/avformat.h>
}
```

It is needed because ffmpeg is a C project and program will not compile with C++ compiler if you don't explicitly state that it is C library.

And if you don't want to bother with `pkg-config` to include all dependencies for ffmpeg libraries, you can install ffmpeg with shared libraries instead of static ones. Then it will compile by simpler call:

```
g++ readVideo.cc -o readVideo -lavformat
```

To install shared libraries, you need to add these 2 options to `./configure` program when installing ffmpeg:

```
--disable-static --enable-shared
```

Hope it helps somebody some time ...

Answer (score 0):

The error means that you aren't linking to the ffmpeg libraries. Simply including the header files is not enough. You need to also link to the actual library files. On Windows they have .lib extension, on Linux usually .a extension, not sure about Mac.

Comment: I tried to link the needed libraries via -libavformat and also pointing the exact paths to static library files, and also tries the dynamic libraries, but it gives me the same error all the time.

Comment: OK, maybe this extra parameter `arch=x86_64` is the culprit. Try building again, and this time run ./configure without it. Don't forget to do `make distclean` before. In general,  configure detects your current architecture anyway, so you shouldn't need to specify it.

Comment: I've tried reinstalling ffmpeg without arch option, still no effect. Is there any way to check that compiler really links the libavformat.a library file? Since I include it in the source file with `#include <libavformat/avformat.h>` and this header file contains problematic function: `av_register_all()`.

Comment: I already told you, just including the header is not enough. If you only include the header without linking to the *.a files, you will get exactly the error you're getting. The linking is not done by the compiler, it is done by the linker (a separate tool). What is the command you're using to compile?

Comment: `gcc readVideo.C -L/usr/local/lib -lavformat` and `gcc readVideo.C /usr/local/lib/libavformat.a`