# A C language ffmpeg project organized with CMakeLists, encounters errors in the Windows MinGW64 environment

Tags: c, ffmpeg, mingw-w64

#### Project Structure

ffmpeg-tutorial

- include

  - libavcodec
  - libavdevice
  - libavfilter
  - libavformat
  - libavutil
  - libswresample
  - libswscale
- lib

  - pkgconfig
  - libavcodec.a
  - libavdevice.a
  - libavfilter.a
  - libformat.a
  - libavutil.a
  - libswresample.a
  - libswscale.a
- CMakeLists.txt
- main.c

#### CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(ffmpeg_tutorial)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)

include_directories(include)
link_directories(lib)
add_executable(ffmpeg_tutorial main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(ffmpeg_tutorial
        avformat
        avcodec
        avutil
        swscale
        swresample
        z
        bz2
        iconv
        ws2_32
        schannel
        kernel32
        advapi32
        kernel32
        user32
        gdi32
        winspool
        shell32
        ole32
        oleaut32
        uuid
        comdlg32
        advapi32
        )
```

#### main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "libavcodec/avcodec.h"
#include "libavformat/avformat.h"
#include "libswresample/swresample.h"
int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    std::cout << av_version_info() << std::endl;
    printf("ffmpeg version is %s\n", av_version_info());
    // Open input file
    AVFormatContext *inputContext = nullptr;
    if (avformat_open_input(&inputContext, "input.mp3", nullptr, nullptr) != 0) {
        printf("Couldn't open input file\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // Read input stream
    if (avformat_find_stream_info(inputContext, nullptr) < 0) {
        printf("Couldn't find stream information\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // Get audio stream index
    int audioStream = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < inputContext->nb_streams; i++) {
        if (inputContext->streams[i]->codecpar->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO) {
            audioStream = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (audioStream == -1) {
        printf("Couldn't find audio stream\n");
        return -1;
    }
}
```

#### IDE

clion

#### ERRORS

```
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/ffmpeg_tutorial.dir/main.cpp.obj
[100%] Linking CXX executable ffmpeg_tutorial.exe
D:/Msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: G:/cywen_private/cpp_projects/ffmpeg-tutorial/lib/libavformat.a(tls_schannel.o): in function `tls_write':
D:\Msys64\usr\src\ffmpeg/libavformat/tls_schannel.c:563: undefined reference to `EncryptMessage'
D:/Msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: G:/cywen_private/cpp_projects/ffmpeg-tutorial/lib/libavformat.a(tls_schannel.o): in function `tls_read':
D:\Msys64\usr\src\ffmpeg/libavformat/tls_schannel.c:441: undefined reference to `DecryptMessage'
D:/Msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: G:/cywen_private/cpp_projects/ffmpeg-tutorial/lib/libavcodec.a(mfenc.o):mfenc.c:(.rdata$.refptr.IID_ICodecAPI[.refptr.IID_ICodecAPI]+0x0): undefined reference to `IID_ICodecAPI'
D:/Msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: G:/cywen_private/cpp_projects/ffmpeg-tutorial/lib/libavcodec.a(tiff.o): in function `tiff_uncompress_lzma':
D:\Msys64\usr\src\ffmpeg/libavcodec/tiff.c:577: undefined reference to `lzma_stream_decoder'
D:/Msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:\Msys64\usr\src\ffmpeg/libavcodec/tiff.c:582: undefined reference to `lzma_code'
D:/Msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:\Msys64\usr\src\ffmpeg/libavcodec/tiff.c:583: undefined reference to `lzma_end'
D:/Msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: G:/cywen_private/cpp_projects/ffmpeg-tutorial/lib/libavutil.a(random_seed.o): in function `av_get_random_seed':
D:\Msys64\usr\src\ffmpeg/libavutil/random_seed.c:127: undefined reference to `BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider'
D:/Msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:\Msys64\usr\src\ffmpeg/libavutil/random_seed.c:130: undefined reference to `BCryptGenRandom'
D:/Msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:\Msys64\usr\src\ffmpeg/libavutil/random_seed.c:131: undefined reference to `BCryptCloseAlgorithmProvider'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles\ffmpeg_tutorial.dir\build.make:95: ffmpeg_tutorial.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:82: CMakeFiles/ffmpeg_tutorial.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:89: CMakeFiles/ffmpeg_tutorial.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:123: ffmpeg_tutorial] Error 2
```

#### What is the way I compile ffmpeg

- ##### downlaod msys2
- ##### install mingw64

```
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain
```

- ##### install make,diffutils,nasm,yasm,pkg-config

```
pacman -S base-devl yasm nasm pkg-config
```

- ##### download ffmpeg 5.1
- ##### compile

```
cd ffmpeg
./configure --disable-shared --enable-static --arch=x86_64 --target-os=mingw32 --cross-prefix=x86_64-w64-mingw32- --pkg-config-flags=--static --prefix=../ffmpeg-build

make -j $(nproc)

make install
```

#### Project Repoistory

`https://github.com/joinwen/learn_ffmpeg.git`

#### Expectation

1. How to solve errors
2. In CMakeLists target_link_libraries's parameters is too much, Can I make it short
3. some advices on the project

Comment: Install  the libraries that ffmpeg rely on.

Answer (score 0):

Found a hint in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13397914/1106547.

I've managed to build and run your example using `pkg-config` to resolve the libs linking part:

```
gcc -o main main.c $(pkg-config --libs --cflags libavformat)
```

Though I replaced the `cout` with `printf` as it's a C code.
And replaced `nullptr` with `NULL`.

First check the `pkg-config --libs --cflags libavformat` prints something.
In my case I had to update the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` variable to indicate where `pkg-config` has to search for libraries.
Like this:

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/
```

So final generated build command I obtained was:

```
gcc -o main main.c -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lavformat -lbz2 -lsecur32 -lws2_32 -lavcodec -liconv -llzma -lz -lole32 -lswresample -lavutil -lm -luser32 -lbcrypt
```